# В чём разница между одиночными и двойными указателями?

Tags: c, указатели

Здравствуйте!

Прошу объяснить разницу между двойными и одиночными указателями на примере двух приведённых ниже программ: они одинаковые, только первая использует одиночные указатели, а вторая - двойные.

Меня интересует, почему в первой программе строка `++(currentChar)` не приводит к движению по строке чисел, а во второй соответствующая строка `++(*currentChar)` приводит, другими словами, почему "область действия одиночного указателя ограничивается функцией, в пределах которой он задан" (кавычки, потому что знаю, что это может быть не точно) ?

Просьба не ругать за отсутствие элементарных познаний в языке C - я постепенно спускаюсь к нему с более высокого уровня (Objective-C), и до сих пор не выдавалось время изучить C системно.

Спасибо.

---

**После ответов и обсуждения выяснилось, что на самом деле ключевая разница (ох, незнание основ!!) состоит в том, как передаются аргументы: в первом случае это просто `currentChar`, а во втором это `&currentChar`. См. ответы и обсуждение.**

---

Программа №1

```
void func1(const char *currentChar) {
    printf("char is %c\n", *currentChar);

    ++(currentChar);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char *JSONCString2 = "123456789";

    const char *currentChar = JSONCString2;

    while (currentChar != NULL && *currentChar != '\0') {
        func1(currentChar);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Её вывод: бесконечное повторяющееся **char is 1**.

Программа №2

```
void func1(const char **currentChar) {
    printf("char is %c\n", **currentChar);

    ++(*currentChar);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char *JSONCString2 = "123456789";

    const char *currentChar = JSONCString2;

    while (currentChar != NULL && *currentChar != '\0') {
        func1(&currentChar);
    }

    return 0;
}

char is 1
char is 2
char is 3
char is 4
char is 5
char is 6
char is 7
char is 8
char is 9
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, в первой программе Вы увеличиваете не указатель из `main`, а его копию, которая и передается в качестве параметра в `func1()` . 

Переменная `currentChar` в `main` просто не меняется.

Почитайте про передачу аргументов в функции по значению и по указателю (адресу, ссылке (не знаю, какой именно термин используют авторы в Ваших книжках)).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Да, я ещё поэкспериментировал и после проб и ошибок стал догадываться о том, что дело в передаче аргументов по значению или по ссылке.

Comment: Ловушка в том, что при разработке на Objective-C необходимость знания многих вещей из чистого С часто можно обойти, за счёт того, что 1) многое есть в Cocoa API из коробки и думать "ниже" не приходится 2) многие вещи можно собезьяничать со SO, Github и др. Поэтому, в целом, я скорее сознательно опускаюсь ниже, чтобы разобраться во всём подробнее. Прямо сейчас, например, я пробую написать почти целиком на C (только output на Objective) игрушечный парсер JSON для того, чтобы разобраться с некоторыми тёмными местами - данный топик возник как раз из одного такого.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, только парсер? 

И почему постейший. Пишите уж достаточно полный (разберетесь с такими "темными" местами, как union, void \* и битовые флаги. Логично ведь, что бы дескрипторы Object, Array, String и значения Number, Null и Bool на самом деле располагались в одном и том же месте в каком-нибудь JsonValue).

А есть идеи о JSON-manipulation интерфейсе из чистого Си?

Comment: О! "Простейший", наверное, потому, что то, что вы перечислили: union, void *, битовые флаги - находится за пределами моих нынешних знаний и потому, что то, что уже написано, не обрабатывает большое количество частных случаев.

Comment: Я сейчас "в отпуске" (кавычки означают лишь формальную незанятость на основной работе), поэтому располагаю свободным временем, чтобы разобраться в том, о чём вы пишите, хотя бы на начальном уровне. Если интересно, я могу рассказать подробнее, что уже написал, и что пытался сделать, только не знаю, где это удобно и наглядно можно сделать. (Я даже готов и лично это обсудить, так как очень-очень интересно).

Comment: Напишите в исследованиях. Там вроде бы количество комментариев не ограничено.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Указатель - это обыкновенная переменная, которая хранит не данные, а некий адрес, который ссылается на ячейку данных. "Размер" этой ячейки зависит от типа указателя (не сам размер, а размер ячейки, которую он адресует, это важно для адресной арифметики, см. далее). Логично, что мы можем делать указатель на указатель с условно бесконечной глубиной вложенности. Можно получать адреса, относительно указателя "сдвигая" его вправо (прибавляя целое число) и влево (отнимая целое число) на размер типа указателя.

**UPD**

В первый раз мы передаем указатель по значению (каждый раз копируем значение), второй раз - по ссылке (работаем с ним непосредственно). Поэтому инкремент в первом случае не работает мы будем "топтаться на месте". из аргумента). Ну и при обращении к строке (в printf) в первый раз мы один раз извлекаем указатель (разыменовываем), а во второй - дважды, получая сначала адрес указателя на данные, а затем - и сами данные.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Отмечу, что разница в программах есть: обратите внимание на вывод у обеих - он различен! Первая программа циклится бесконечно, а вторая - работает как нужно. Именно эту разницу я и хочу понять.

Comment: Понял вас. Обновил второй абзац ответа.

Comment: > @Stanislaw Pankevich, я глянул по Вашей сылке на жасмин, (может не до конца понял), но что-то мне не очень нравится столь формальный парсинг только на токены. Наверное имеет смысл продолжить в исследованиях.

Согласен и согласен. Прежде, чем я начну исследование, два вопроса:

1. Мне же стоит подготовить проект к исследованию (скажем на Github) или будем обсуждать "стратегию", "на пальцах"? Хочется просто на каком-то коде всё это посмотреть.

2. Если первое да, то есть ли у вас возможность запустить clang с ObjC или мне вырезать весь ObjC код?

P.S. Хочу выбрать удачную форму для иссл.

Comment: Опубликовал [исследование](http://hashcode.ru/research/291943/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80-json-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c-objective-c).

Answer (score 6):

Давайте-ка и я добавлю свои пять копеек.

Дело в том, что указатель в C используется в нескольких различных смыслах.

Во-первых, это настоящий указатель — адрес какой-то переменной в памяти.

Затем, это может быть массив неопределённой длины (которую приходится передавать отдельно). Вместо отдельного типа данных для массива в C пользуются указателем на первый элемент (то есть элемент с индексом 0).

Как специальный случай, строка в C очень похожа по логике на массив: это массив символов (который обычным образом представляется в виде указателя на начальный символ), но текущая *длина* строки определяется неявно, позицией первого нулевого символа (и может не совпадать с длиной выделенного куска памяти).

Наконец, указатель используется для семантики «передать переменную так, чтобы вызываемая процедура могла её поменять». Для этого передаётся указатель на эту переменную, а вызывающий код разыменовывает этот указатель.

Таким образом, каждая из `*` в коде может иметь одно из упомянутых выше значений. А значит, значение `**` не фиксировано, его приходится каждый раз определять из контекста.

---

Конкретно для вашего случая: в C всё, в том числе и указатели, передаётся *по значению*: параметр является *копией* аргумента, а не самим аргументом. Изменения в копии указателя не приводят к изменению самого указателя.

Передачи «по ссылке» нет, и её приходится эмулировать, как описано выше. У вас во втором примере так и происходит: вы передаёте указатель на ваш указатель (то есть, конечно, его *копию*). Но и копия, и оригинал указателя указывают на *одни и те же данные* (то есть, на один и тот же `char *`), поэтому изменения в этих данных, понятно, «видны» всем.

Comment: Спасибо. В таком виде, гораздо более понятно. Особенно помогли для ясности последние два абзаца.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich: добавил ещё, конкретно по вашему случаю.

Comment: @VladD, наверное (конечно, формально) параметр не всегда копия аргумента. Например, в

    printf ("%d", 2 * 2);

второй аргумент это именно значение выражения `2 * 2`, а не копия 4-ки (по крайней мере хочется хорошо думать об оптимизации в компиляторе :)).

Comment: @avp, отвечаю здесь (там лимит) - 

> Напишите в исследованиях. Там вроде бы количество комментариев не ограничено.

Нужно тогда уточнить scope. Я пытался сделать вот такое - написать JSON-парсер для Objective-C, который пробегает и разбирает исходную строку с пом. C, а продукцию (Objects, Arrays, Numbers, Strings) на лету кладёт в Objective-C объекты. В принципе мне это удалось, только я не доволен скоростью по сравнению с Apple API: даже когда я убираю аллокации Objective-C объектов (разбор идёт без генерации ObjC-объектов) - Apple API раза в 2-3 быстрее. Это может быть первая тема для иссл

Comment: Вторая тема - это написать что-то вроде [jsmn](https://bitbucket.org/zserge/jsmn/) - только сделать это так, чтобы он работал по-настоящему быстро - по моим сравнениям jsmn просто разбирает токены, а Apple API за то же время 5-10 раза успевает создать полновесные Objective-C Dictionaries & Arrays.

Comment: Для практики, мне конечно ближе первая тема, но может быть можно было бы для начала написать второе, а первое сделать как Objective-C bindings к первому и так, чтобы они славно дружили по скорости и изяществу. Что скажете? Интересно звучит?

Comment: @avp: Это тонкий вопрос равенства и идентичности объектов. нашем случае должна быть именно _копия_ четвёрки. Иначе вот такой код:

    void inc(int n) { n++; }
    void print(int n) { printf("%d\n", n); }
    inc(4); print(4);

вывел бы 5, так первый код увеличил бы объект, обозначаемый в программе литералом `4`!

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, я глянул по Вашей сылке на жасмин, (может не до конца понял), но что-то мне не очень нравится столь формальный парсинг только на токены. 

Наверное имеет смысл продолжить в **исследованиях**.

Comment: @VladD, если посмотреть правде в глаза, то в реальности (в С/C++/фортране и т.п.) такого объекта, как 4 просто не существует (в отличии от строковых (и м.б. некотрых других) констант). 

В случае значения выражения это ведь просто текущее состояние выхода АЛУ, отображаемое на регистр (и в зависимости от архитектуры на память в стеке). 

В случае константы (inc(4)) скорее всего часть битиков, образующих машинную инструкцию.

Comment: @avp: Но это ведь подробности имплементации, правда? Семантика операции определяется языком, а не имплементацией, а язык ничего про регистры, процессор и даже само его наличие в системе не говорит. И значит, отличие строкового литерала от числового должно быть описано в языке, а имплементация должна это реализовать (настолько возможно эффективно).

Кстати, в древних версиях Фортрана был, как мне рассказывали, смешной баг, когда компилятор таки располагал константу по физическому адресу, а процедура получала не копию, а оригинал — в результате можно было изменить **значение** литерала 0.

Comment: @VladD, формально Вы безусловно правы. 

Но, в любом случае, на самом-то деле лучше иметь представление о деталях реализации и действовать в соответствии со здравым смыслом.

Конечно, **в данном случае** это абсолютно никакого значения не имеет (просто или в стеке или в каком-то из регисторов в inc() передается 0...100b и как это место не меняй, в вызывающей функции ничего не  изменится).

Comment: @avp: Непременно! Надо знать свой инструмент наизусть, как свои пять пальцев.

---
Мне кажется, популярность языка C как раз и обусловлена тем, что его абстракции близки к железу, и практически прямо соответствуют тому, что делает скомпилированный код. Поэтому поведение _литерала_ 4 совпадает с поведением _значения_ 4 в регистре процессора. И поведение литерала `"abc"` совпадает с поведением указателя на начало строки в том же самом регистре.